# JPA: join a column based on some condition

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have to table

```
table A : personID, name, someOtherColumns (personID is primarykey)
table B:  personAliasID, personID, personAias, someOtherColumns (personAliasID is primary key)
```

one person can have muliple personAlias. Whant I want to do is to get a table A entity based on personID and a certain personAlias. Entity A should also has a instance field B b (as code shown below) so that I can access information in entity B for this person.

here's my code

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name="A")
    public class A implement Serializable {
        ...
        ...
       //find the column in B where personAlias="someName"       
       @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="personID", referencedColumnName = "personID"
          private B b;

    }
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent the join you are looking for you can do the following:

```
...
public class A implements Serializable
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = ...) // assuming you are generating values for personId
    private long personId;
...
```

and

```
...
public class B implements Serializable
...
    @JoinColumn(name="personId", nullable=false)
    @ManyToOne
    private A person;
```

Then to create such an object in your code you can do something like this:

```
A a = ... // create person object for person with appropriate personID
B b = ...
b.setPerson(a);
b.setPersonAlias(alias);
```

But to simply query based on those tables, you may as well create an `@NamedQuery` on `A` to perform the query you want.
Here is how you can get an entity `A` for `personID` an a variable `personAlias`:

e.g.

```
...
@NamedQuery(name = "A.personByAlias", query = "select a from A a, B b"
            + " where a.personId = b.personId and b.personAlias = :personAlias")
public class A implements Serializable
...
```

Then call:

```
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("A.personByAlias");
    query.setParameter("personAlias", id);
    List<A> result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks. with this namedquery, I can get an object a. how can I access this person's alias and other information stored in table B?

Comment: You can use `em.find(B.class, pkey)` see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)

Comment: Or class A can reference B using a OneToMany(mappedby="person") making the relationship bidirectional.  You would use a Collection in A for this as it can have many Bs or aliases.

Comment: hey neo, please consider accepting my answer if its satisfied your question. thanks!